# Realtime conversion of ARFrame.capturedImage CVPixelBufferRef to OpenCv Mat

Tags: ios, opencv, arkit

ARKit runs at 60 frames/sec, which equates to 16.6ms per frame.

My current code to convert the CVPixelBufferRef (kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange format) to a cv::Mat (YCrCb) runs in 30ms, which causes ARKit to stall and everything to lag.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to to a quicker conversion or do I need to drop the frame rate?

There is a [suggestion by Apple to use Metal](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2867984-capturedimage), but I'm not sure how to do that.

Also I could just take the grayscale plane, which is the first channel, which runs in <1ms, but ideally I need the colour information as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to convert Ycbcr to RGB, do image processing in RGB mat and convert it back to Ycbcr, **it worked very slowly**. I suggest only do that with a static image. For realtime processing, we should process directly in cv::Mat. ARFrame.capturedImage is Ycbcr buffer. So, the solution is

1. Sperate the buffer to 2 cv::Mat (yPlane and cbcrPlane). Keep in mind, we do not clone memory, we create 2 cv::Mat with base addresses is yPlane address and cbcrPlane address.
2. Do image process on yPlane and cbcrPlane, size(cbcrPlane) = size(yPlane) / 2.

You can check out my code here: https://gist.github.com/ttruongatl/bb6c69659c48bac67826be7368560216

Comment: I can't figure out how to convert to RGBA. Can you help me out with that?

Comment: Is it possible to create a single Mat holding all the information instead of having two Mats yPlane and cbcrPlane?

Comment: two Mats yPlane and cbcrPlane help our code more clear. As I said, we do not clone memory. You may need to write one more function to convert RGB to RGBA.

Answer (score 3):

In order to process an image in a pixel buffer using Metal, you need to do following.

1. Call CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage to create CVMetalTexture object on top of the pixel buffer.
2. Call CVMetalTextureGetTexture to create a MTLTexture object, which Metal code (GPU) can read and write.
3. Write some Metal code to convert the color format.

I have an open source project (https://github.com/snakajima/vs-metal), which processes pixel buffers (from camera, not ARKit) using Metal. Feel free to copy any code from this project.